# VisualVM or YourKit - Is it possible to profile CPU usages in idle state?

Tags: java, performance, netbeans, cpu-usage, metrics

I need to find the percent of time that a process is idle and the average period of background tasks with no load and average period of background tasks with some load.

I'm not trying to find problems with the profilers.  Instead, I need to document performance metrics graphically.

I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616252/1735836).

I think I need to put loggers in idle code but I don't know how to find the idle code.

Comment: first you need to determine when the process is idle or not-idle. then you can bin measurements based on time-spans spent in either state

Comment: @the8472 - I have updated my related question with more information.  Thank you for the hint and I will be looking in to this.  Please take a look at my other question and see if there is any additional information you might be able to give me.  Since nobody else is answering, I'd like to give you the points.